# How to use multiple lines on an inputbox?

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for help to use multiple lines on a VBS input box.
I want it to look like this:

> Please enter one of the listed letters!
>  
>   a.
>  
>   b.
>   c.
>   d.

I wasn't able to find any helpful information on how to do it. I've messed around a bit but nothing seems to work. I've seem some things about (Chr(13)) and stuff but have no idea how to use it in syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`result = InputBox("Please enter one of the listed letters!" & vbNewLine & "a." & vbNewline & "b." & vbNewLine & "c." & vbNewLine & "d.", "InputBoxTitle")`